# composerコマンドで特定のパッケージのみ追加したい

Tags: php, laravel, composer

composerコマンドで特定のパッケージのみ追加したいのですが、
既存のパッケージまでアップデートされてしまいます。

具体的な内容としましてはLaravel5.1.xに
「maatwebsite/excel」のパッケージを追加しようとして
下記のコマンドを打ち込んでいます。

> $ composer require maatwebsite/excel

他のパッケージをアップデートせず、
新しくパッケージを追加する場合はどのようにコマンドを打ち込めばよろしいのでしょうか?

お手数ですが、ご回答よろしくお願い致します。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

こちらのバージョンから既存のパッケージに影響がでないバージョンを選択してバージョンアップするしかないと思います。

https://packagist.org/packages/maatwebsite/excel

ただし、古いバージョンをインストールすることになりますので、
リスクは自己責任となるのでご注意ください。